# Bullet point won't appear in HTML, instead shows random characters

Tags: html, css

I used "Option + 8" to write a bullet point into my html document. The bullet point appears in the DreamWeaver program I'm using as well as the JSFiddle but shows random characters when I try to run the HTML file, as so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv2TS.jpg

I'm not sure why this is happening, or why the random character appears in the top left hand corner.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJB2Q/3/)

Requisite Code:

```
#slide-1 li{

display: inline;
width: 400px;
color: #b2b2b2;
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: you should use an html entity.

Comment: As Daniel said you should use an HTML entity. Try `&bull;`.

Comment: And what does your HTTP header declare as the encoding?

Comment: ^answers to questions should be posted in the answers area below for better continuity and post-metric efficacy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the bullet point using its entity code, either `&bull;` or `&bullet;`

**Useful:**
http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMcNaught/DJB2Q/4/

Answer (score 4):

The issue your facing is an encoding one. That is, when you hit `opt + 8` on your computer, your computer knows that that command is bound to a certain character in memory.

However, because of the huge variety of computers in the world, its likely that when people do similar things errors will eventually occur—the number of encodings for different languages, environments, and customization all make it so that misunderstandings will happen.

The best solution is to, as often as you can (not everything is standardized across everything, of course) use whatever the most widely-understood and best-supported standard is. Here, it's **`&bull;`** instead of whatever you pasted in.

This is a best practice in general, especially since just copying/pasting from your computer to a file can give you a false-positive.

Hope this helps! It's a simple fix, but a larger issue that could save you a **TON** of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying the Character Encoding set as so:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```