# How to replace bullets with &bull;

Tags: php, html

I am retrieving text data from a database which includes bullets and newlines. I have successfully removed the newlines and converted them to `<br />` using the `nl2br()` function in PHP, but the bullets act weird and display "â€¢" instead of "•" (see screenshot).

[image]

I have tried using `htmlspecialchars()` function in PHP but it still displays the same output.

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved it myself using `htmlentities()` instead of `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bullet point won't appear in HTML, instead shows random characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398130/bullet-point-wont-appear-in-html-instead-shows-random-characters)

Answer (score 3):

I have used `htmlentities()` now instead of `htmlspecialchars`. I have solved my own problem but I hope this thread will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character `U+2022 (BULLET)` is encoded in UTF-8 as the octets `E2` `80` `A2`. If your page contains these octets, and the page is incorrectly interpreted using a different character encoding, such as [Windows-1252](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT), the resulting page will display the three characters `â`, `€`, `¢`.

To properly display the bullet character, you need to declare the correct character encoding for your document:

```
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If it is not feasible to use the UTF-8 encoding, you can convert the string using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which should convert the bullet characters, and other undisplayable characters, into HTML character references (`&bull;`):

```
$s = "Bullet \xe2\x80\xa2 character";
echo htmlentities ($s), "\n";
```

Or, if PHP's character encoding is not configured correctly:

```
$s = "Bullet \xe2\x80\xa2 character";
echo htmlentities ($s, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'), "\n";
```