# CSS icons under Chrome are weirdly displayed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, icons

I've added a bullet icon in CSS with the following code: `content: "\2022";`

**Firefox**: It works as expected

**Chrome**: Sometimes, for no particular reason, the icons are not interpreted and are displayed with strange characters instead

**Weird behavior**
[image]

**Expected behavior**
[image]

When doing researches, a lot of people were talking about UTF-8 but when compiled, my app.css is already in UTF-8: `@charset "UTF-8";`
My HTML file is also in UTF-8: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

```
&::before {
    color: $primary;
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
```

The fact that it happens only sometimes and only under Chrome is something that I don't really understand and I don't know what to look up for.

Is there something I could do to fix this problem ? It's really annoying and the only way to get rid of it it's to clear the cache of the browser.

Thank you !

Comment: Please could you provide a runnable snippet which you have tested and which definitely shows the problem In particular did you mean the double backslash - with  a single one I cannot reproduce your problem. Also what fonts are you using?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look carefully at the fonts that are being used - and try to create a snippet which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested `content: "\\2022";` and it throws an error. Consider using `content: "\2022";` or correcting the question.

Also, try using `&bull` or `&bullet` HTML property instead of css.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Original Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24398195/11109227

Comment: How can an HTML special character like &bull; work for the content property?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Corrected the answer.

Comment: So this doesn't answer the question in fact, since the question is about setting content.

Comment: I tried to add `&bull` in the HTML and I can't tell you if it works or not because I didn't test it long enough.
Tbh I would like to keep it in the CSS because it's in a pseudo element.
We also have the problems with Tagify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRWLi.png
So best case scenario I would like to understand/fix the problem the way it is

Comment: I have tested your snippet, and I cannot reproduce the issue.